# How to capture images that are suitable for OCR

Tags: camera, android-camera, ocr

I'm reading about which factors can be changed to enhance the accuracy of text recognition in an image  BEFORE the image is taken. Basically I'm interested in lighting and  various camera settings like exposure and shutter speed.

I've found mostly papers on improving camera focus [like this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6830994&queryText%3Docr+accuracy!) but since autofocus seems common nowadays I'm not sure special efforts need to be taken to adjust focus. But I could not find much on the lighting and camera settings for OCR(I'm interested in handheld cameras).

So, how do I choose the ideal lighting and camera sensors settings in a handheld camera such that the image is suitable for OCR?